# How to gracefully handle 404 in Angular component?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I am using Angular 6.
And in this specific use case want to handle 404, rather pass it along to the component to display a text message in the UI.

```
// code in service
public getVariatioMarginPlugDates(): Observable<Date[]> {
return this._http
              .get<Date[]>(AppSettings.VariationMarginPlugDatesUrl, { withCredentials: true })
              .pipe(catchError(this._trace.handleError('GET ' + AppSettings.VariationMarginPlugDatesUrl, [])));
}
```

The `404` is also being handled by `catchError` that uses an error handler utility. However I want to trap the 404 and potentially set some boolean variable which the component could use to display a useful status message on the UI (not looking for `404` redirect or generic popup)

Thank you so much!

```
// edited code with solution
public getVariatioMarginEmail(runDate: string): Observable<any> {
const url = AppSettings.VariationMarginEmailUrl.replace(this._regExp, runDate);
return this._http
              .get<any>(url, { withCredentials: true })
              .catch(this._trace.handleError('GET ' + url, []));
}

public handleError<T>(operation = 'operation',  result?: T, skipStatus = [404]) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      if (skipStatus.includes(error.status)) {
        return observableOf(error.status as T);
      }

      const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
      console.error(errMsg);

      const dialog = this._dialogService.open({
        title: 'Server Error',
        content: `${operation} failed: ${errMsg}`,
        actions: [ { text: 'Ok' } ]
      });

      try { this._loggingService.log(errMsg); } catch (error) {}

      return observableOf(result as T); // return empty result
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't really have a concrete answer for doing this, but perhaps an error interceptor that pushes the errors to a subject on a service, and then the component can subscribe to see when errors happen. Then you can do whatever logic you need to update the component, and others components can use it as well. Although perhaps this requires more code than you would like to write. And I'm guessing you're looking to catch the error for a particular request.

Comment: Hi Wingnod, I have a `handleError` which pop ups a dialog with an appropriate `NotFound` message however in this request, I want the component to display a message in a specific place in the UI so don't want the `handleError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the handle error method, couple of choices:

1) Don't put it in the pipe here. Then your component will get the error, and you can check the status code and handle how you need to

2) Alter the handle method to check the status, and rethrow 404's that the component can handle. You could do this if you still want other logging, etc in the handleError method

3) Alter the handle method to take a configuration telling it which status to skip, 404. You could do this if some components should get the generic method, but this component specifically should handle its error itself

Comment: thanks for the ideas, 3) seems the use case for me - I will try this out!

Comment: Awesome, nice job!